How to get on to the roof?
I have a house with a Gable Roof. By eyeballing it looks like it's slanted at about 45 degrees and one side is approximately 6 meters (20 feet) long.
Since it's a pretty old roof, there are a few small holes and cracks in it. While there are some good reasons for replacing it entirely, that's a big and expensive project for which I don't have the funds right now. The holes are small enough to be patched with some bitumen tape, so that's what I'd like to do.
Buuut... how do I get up there? I mean, I have a decent ladder which can reach the lower edge of the roof and a little beyond that, but it's nowhere near long enough to reach the top (or even the lowest hole to be patched). In addition I highly doubt the roof tiles would support my weight if I was to just walk on them.
I've seen people use special roof ladders for this purpose. They're like normal ladders, but at the very end there's a perpendicular section. You hook that perpendicular section on the ridge and then can safely climb that on the roof. Your weight is then distributed over a larger area via the roof ladder.
However I cannot find anyone selling such a ladder. I could attempt to make one myself out of wood, but I don't trust my woodworking skills enough to make something that won't suddenly come apart under load.
I suspect that there must be some other method that people are using these days to access diagonal roofs, since they are still quite common around here. What am I missing?

Are you sure that you have a "tile" roof? (these would more likely be concrete "tiles") A 45-degree slope would be used so snow will slide off the roof, and tile roofs are generally used where there is no snow. If you really have a tile roof, then you need to worry about cracking the tiles when you walk on them. Search "walking on a tile roof".

@Mattman944 I'm not really sure what it's called. It looks like this (image found on Google). It's pretty old so most likely contains asbestos. It's also fairly fragile and would totally not support someone simply standing on it. Underneath it you have the normal large roof beams which are then covered with an even older roof made of... thin wooden planks? Bark? Not sure. Can take pictures on the weekend. The "tiles" are nailed to the beams and some other planks perpendicular to them.

@Mattman944 "Fiber cement roof" perhaps? Google translate says "slate", "shale" and "schist", but the images I get searching for those are not it.

OK, I am not familiar with that type of roof. I have only seen much smaller tiles. But the issue is similar, you need something to distribute the weight, they sell a product for this purpose, a high-density foam with plastic on top. https://roofsmartpads.com It is probably expensive. I have also seen roofers use what looked like high-density foam sheets without any top layer, but these wouldn't work well on your steep roof.

@Mattman944 - The last time someone was on that roof was... don't remember, 10 years ago or so? I was there and helped (from the ground). They replaced the ridge and used a simple wooden ladder to get up there, after which they sat on the ridge. So I know it's sturdy enough for that.

Patches are just temporary. Get a quote from a professional tiler to re-tile your current roof. In the long term, this will be your cheapest option.

@JeremyBoden No doubt about it. And it's not even close to the only thing that the house needs repaired. I checked out some websites for roofing materials and got a rough estimate for the cost of the materials alone. It started at about 3500€. We're still contemplating about what to do with that house.

Check the attic how the roof is constructed, chances are there is plywood or similar between the rafters. That will easily support your weight (assuming it's not rotten).
The more dangerous aspect is slipping and falling down. 45° slope is very steep and once you start sliding you will have a very hard time stopping yourself.
You can buy roof ladder hooks.

(image from a random amazon listing)
That will attach to your regular ladder and let you hook the ladder to the nook. The wheels are there to get the ladder up or down, you roll the ladder up and then flip it to hook it on. To get it down you flip it over and can then roll it down the roof.

Another option is to place a roof anchor(s) at the ridge, depending on your roof construction and whether you can reach the ridge from the gable end.  Then get yourself a harness.

Now that I know what to look for, I was able to find this in my local home improvement store.

Wood backing under the roofing material is also called "sarking"
